# ASP-Classic Crossdomain upload issue

Tags: flash, asp-classic, upload, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I've been working on an old upload function on a website that is made using ASP-classic. It has a flash file that acts as the interface for the uploader, which seems to be working. I press upload after selecting an image file, but then it presents me with the following error:
"An Security Error, 'securitySandboxError' occured. May be you trying to upload/download files outside current domain (See "Cross Domain Security" section in manual".

The client-side uploader looks like this:

```
                        <div id="flashupload">
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=cmsDir%>gallery/gallerylib/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            AC_FL_RunContent('id','FlashFilesUpload','codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','100%','height','350','bgcolor','#F8F6E6','src','<%=cmsDir%>gallery/gallerylib/ElementITMultiPowUpload1.6','quality','High','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','flashvars','<%=fVars%>','movie','<%=cmsDir%>gallery/gallerylib/ElementITMultiPowUpload1.6','wmode','Window','menu','false' ); //end AC code
                        </script>
                        <noscript>
                        <object id="FlashFilesUpload" codeBase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="500" height="350" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
                        <PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE="<%=fVars%>">
                        <PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="<%=cmsDir%>/gallery/gallerylib/ElementITMultiPowUpload1.6.swf">
                        <PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="<%=cmsDir%>/gallery/gallerylib/ElementITMultiPowUpload1.6.swf">
                        <PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Window">
                        <PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High">
                        <PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="false">
                        <embed bgcolor="#F8F6E6" id="EmbedFlashFilesUpload" src="<%=cmsDir%>gallery/gallerylib/ElementITMultiPowUpload1.6" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="350" flashvars="<%=fVars%>"></embed>
                        </object>
                        </noscript>
                        </div>
```

The server-side code is too huge to display, and I don't know how to take out the relevant parts. Either way, we're using the code from the following side: http://www.freeaspupload.net/

(Seems to be down, sorry)

I have no experience with this, but as the error implies I assumed that it had something to do with the crossdomain file. I added one to my root, and tried many different variants but to no avail. The error remains the same.

The console displays the following error:

```
GET http://siteditor/crossdomain.xml net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Does this mean it's not detecting my crossdomain file? Either way, it's not the location of my crossdomain file.

Sincerely Yours,
Nick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: This script is too large to simply replace with JQuery and Ajax. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should'nt be getting this error if you're doing it server-side in the first place.

Comment: Agreed, could just be a misleading error message.

Comment: Are you sure the request isn't going through client side? Thus, would be causing the cross-domain restriction

Comment: I have completely deleted the uploader and re-created it using JQuery, PHP and HTML. I couldn't figure out the problem, sorry.